# In Wordpress website, connecting to another web_based application

Tags: wordpress

I want to create a page in word press website, that shows information from external `DB by API`. What should I do?

But other pages and theme are in the `Wordpress database`.
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Set up a custom template.  It can contain all the custom code you need, such as the API to call the external database.  You create a new template by copying and modifying the page.php file from your theme.  Just remove the parts you don't want and at the top put your new template name in a comment line like this:

```
 /* Template Name: External-DB-Page */
```

Save that to a file such as external_db.php, upload it to your theme or child theme directory and then in your functions.php you include the file by adding

```
require_once 'external_db.php';
```

This new template called "External-DB-Page" will now be a selection available when choosing a page template for any page in WordPress.

Comment: Please do not attempt to answer low quality questions that do not meet SO community standards.  You only encourage that kind of behavior and are providing a generalized solution to an unclear problem.